# Remove occurrences of string in text file

Tags: linux, windows, text, command-line

How would you remove a specific string from a text file (command line) e.g.

```
hello
goodbye
goodbye
hello
hello
hello
goodbye
```

In this case I would like to remove all occurrences of "goodbye"

Either linux or Windows, (as longs as the linux command is available in GNU)

Comment: please say something about the intended language. Do you want a shell script, a C program, ...?

Comment: @Christian Rau Anything really, although no Python or perl, I am on a Windows system and have restrictions

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/goodbye//g' filename
```

To delete multiple words:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(goodbye\|hello\|test\|download\)//g' filename
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: How could I define multiple entries of phrases? e.g. sed -i -e 's/goodbye,hello,test,download//g' filename ??

Comment: Thanks, @linuts. I know I'm not supposed to do that but I had no other option :D

Comment: what about reading in mutliple words from a file instead of hardcoding into a sed command?

Comment: I had to escape pipe as well i.e. `sed 's/\(hello\|goodbye\)//g'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Linux file through Vi mode. Please find below solution which helped me out

:g/goodbye/d - This will delete all goodbye's

:%g!/goodbye/d - This will delete all except goodbye's

*Even if you're using a Windows machine, you can download and configure the **Ubuntu shell** and use the above commands*.

Comment: In which language or tool do you use this?

Comment: linux and vi mode

Comment: I was trying to do same on a linux file. Came across here so thought will put my solution in case future if someone looking for solution through vim.

Answer (score 0):

Best **solution** for me without using `sed` that requires escaping characters when using more complex strings like **paths** and **commands**.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

REPLACE_LINE() {
    file_content=$(<$1)
    file_content=${file_content//$2/$3}
    echo "$file_content" > $1
}

file=./your_file.txt
line="cd /path/to/some/folder && do --some=stuff &"

# Remove
REPLACE_LINE "$file" "$line"

# Replace
REPLACE_LINE "$file" "$line" "your_new_command_here"
```