# Sed find and delete single word

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to remove a username from a `.htaccess` file.

Example `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~usern/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~usern/index.php [L]
```

I want to us a sort of dynamic command in that I don't have to manually type `/~username` every time for each user.

I tried

```
sed 's/$whoami##g' .htaccess
```

but this does not achieve the desired result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove occurrences of string in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998454/608639), [How to replace multiple patterns at once with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26568952/608639), [How can I delete words from each line of a file using sed in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43329477/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `sed -i "s/$(whoami)//g" .htaccess`

If you only want to remove the first entry on a line, remove the last `g` option.

`sed -i (inline sed, do actions directly on file) "s/find_this/replace_with_this/" (search and replace)`

If you want to search for ~/username and remove that instead of only username entries, just change the expression to:

`sed -i "s/~\/$(whoami)//g" .htaccess`

Comment: We are close! what if we are trying to remove /~username not ~/username

Comment: As simple as it was! I did finally get this thanks to your original command just had to move \ couple spots over. Very much appreciated help!   sed -i "s/\/~$(whoami)//g" .htaccess

Comment: @NewBasher Ah yeah, sorry. `~/` is *nix way of getting to home directory, but in an url it's ofc `/~user`. Glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for `s` in sed:

```
 sed 's#/~usern##g' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat file
RewriteEngine On<br />
RewriteBase /~usern/<br />
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]<br />
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br />
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br />
RewriteRule . /~usern/index.php [L]<br />

kent$  sed 's#/~usern##g' file
RewriteEngine On<br />
RewriteBase /<br />
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]<br />
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br />
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br />
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]<br />
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Right after I posted the question I thought of something to speed up the process more, how would I add the 'whoami' in there to search my accounts username instead of manually having to put in the ~username

Comment: you mean `sed "s#/$USER##" file` ? better update your question for that.

Comment: thanks updated most question, $USER wasn't working for me either

Comment: As @Kent said: the way to whipe `\\ ` is there! `sed "s#/$(whoami)##"` must work finely!

Answer (score 1):

#### Instead of *dropping* old version, why not store them as comment:

When I do some modif on configuration files, I like to do a lot of backups, in order to be able to get older configuration if something wrong.

So, instead of *replacing*, I prefer to make a *commented copy* of the old line (and ensure to modify only uncommented desired lines):

```
sed -re "s/^(\s*Rewrite.*)\/~$(whoami)(.*$)/# &\n\1\2/" -i.bak .htaccess
```

Than `diff -u .htaccess{.bak,}` will produce:

```
--- .htaccess.bak   2013-09-07 18:44:07.043537404 +0200
+++ .htaccess       2013-09-07 18:46:35.236454686 +0200
@@ -1,6 +1,8 @@
 RewriteEngine On<br />
-RewriteBase /~usern/<br />
+# RewriteBase /~usern/<br />
+RewriteBase /<br />
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]<br />
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br />
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br />
-RewriteRule . /~usern/index.php [L]<br />
+# RewriteRule . /~usern/index.php [L]<br />
+RewriteRule . /index.php [L]<br />
```

#### Explanation:

*Finding a line containing `Rewrite.*usern`. Replacing this line by a comment mark (`#`), followed by the entire line, than a `newline` and the same line without `usern`*

Because `\s*` is **in** the parenthesis, any kind of indentation will be reproduced at output.

When `sed` is run with the switch `-i.bak`, older unmodified version of file will be stored as `.htaccess.bak` (This could be a little *redundant* with the syntaxe `/# &\n...` who would duplicate and comment unmodified old lines).

It's only for sample, so you have choice:

- backup old files while editing
- backup old lines while editing
- backup both lines and files while editing
- backup nothing as you already have a strong and efficient backup solution.