# How can I delete words from each line of a file using sed in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For e.g. I want to delete the second and the fourth word of each line

Before sample.txt:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nulla elit dui, fermentum sed quam sed, semper auctor elit.
```

After sample.txt:

```
Lorem dolor amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nulla dui, sed quam sed, semper auctor elit.
```

Comment: I resolved with 'cut', but I must you 'sed', which I do not know how to use well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
sed 's/\(\S\+\s\+\)\S\+\s\+\(\S\+\s\+\)\S\+\s\+\(.*\)/\1\2\3/g'
```

should work, if you must use sed.  This script does not work if you have fewer than 4 words in the line.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I could resolve with 'cut' but I must use 'sed' unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with "cut"

```
cut -d ' ' -f1,3,5- MY_FILE
```

The `-d` sets the delimiter to space and the `-f` chooses fields 1, 3 and 5+.

Comment: I must use 'sed', but thanks anyway, this works fine.