# Remove match word from file

Tags: linux, bash

The Data in the File1.txt is

```
Raj cmd
Rahul cmd
Pooja cmd
Vilas cmd
Vikram cmd
```

I want the Output to be Printed like this below

```
Raj
Rahul
Pooja
Vilas
Vikram
```

**The Word I want to remove is "cmd"**

Comment: Pick a programming language or general text processing tool. As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask] as well. Also, don't blindly apply tags, read their description instead, and don't repeat tags in the title either.

Comment: [Remove occurrences of string in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998454/608639), [Sed find and delete single word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15855735/608639), [How can I delete words from each line of a file using sed in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43329477/608639), [How to replace multiple patterns at once with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26568952/608639), and friends.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) question to me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
sed 's/\s*cmd//' File1.txt
```

**explanation**

```
s/   # substitute
\s*  # ignore blanks
cmd  # your pattern
//   # replace with nothing
```