# Print text after last slash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a Data => File1.txt

**Data**

```
@demo/file/wk/Fil0.fk
@demo/file/wk/Fil1.fk
@demo/file/wk/Fil2.fk
@demo/file/wk/Fil3.fk
@demo/file/wk/Fil4.fk
```

**Want to Print the data to Another File2.txt in below Format**

```
Fil0.fk
Fil1.fk
Fil2.fk
Fil3.fk
Fil4.fk
```

Comment: cat File1.txt | cut -d'/' -f 4 > File2.txt

Comment: @GovindParashar ... Thanks !!! ..... I will post another Question which is similar to this but this Some what complex ... Could you be able to fix that complex one

Comment: As Ulrich asked in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393207/remove-match-word-from-file#comment99385356_56393207), please pick a programming language or general text processing tool. As a new user, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
cat File1.txt | cut -d'/' -f 4 > File2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks !!! ..... I will post another Question which is similar to this but this Some what complex ... Could you be able to fix that complex one