# How to extract text from large text

Tags: linux, bash

**I have Data which is in this format in FILE1.txt**

```
@E/f1/w/ @H/abc/w/ @demo/file/wk/Fil0.fk
@E/f2/w/ @H/cdv/w/ @demo/file/wk/Fil1.fk
@E/f3/w/ @H/efg/w/ @demo/file/wk/Fil2.fk
@E/f4/w/ @H/mno/w/ @demo/file/wk/Fil3.fk
@E/f5/w/ @H/pqr/w/ @demo/file/wk/Fil4.fk
```

**I want to Print data to a File .... FILE2.txt in this Below Format**

```
Fil0.fk
Fil1.fk
Fil2.fk
Fil3.fk
Fil4.fk
```

Comment: As Ulrich asked in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393207/remove-match-word-from-file#comment99385356_56393207) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56394666/608639)), please pick a programming language or general text processing tool. As a new user, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as well.

Comment: How could you not get from your other question that you just need to increase the number of / after which to cut !?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always show what you tried.

Assuming filename `x`,

with `cut`:

```
$: cut -d/ -f 10 x
```

with `sed`:

```
$: sed 's#^.*/##' x
```

with `awk`:

```
$: awk  ' { gsub("^.*/",""); print; }' x
```

pure `bash`:

```
$: while read line; do echo "${line//*\/}"; done < x
```

Comment: awesome bro !! Thanks Working as Expected

Comment: But you still should always make an effort first. Someone downvoted me, likely because I gave an answer at all, and they are not wrong... Please always make an effort.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

I Assuming that you want to save the first and second columns in new files.

You have to create a bash like bellow in the path where the FILE1.txt exists, change it to an executable file with `chmod +x <bash_file_name>` command and run it by `./<bash_file_name>`

```
#!/bin/bash

input="FILE1.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # Extract file name
    filename=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d'/' -f4`

    # Extract data
    clumnOne=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}'`
    clumnTwo=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}'`

    # Write to file
    echo "$clumnOne $clumnTwo" >> $filename
done < "$input"
```

Comment: it gives me this error  ...  f.sh: line 28: $filename: ambiguous redirect

Comment: The script provided by Ali only has 16 lines. It is not possible to have an error on line 28. You need to show your code, and clearly state where you are having trouble.

Comment: This is because you probably changed the script for your use, please show your script and text file for solving.